# Schatten norm estimate of spatially truncated resolvent of Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, integral-operators

Consider the operator $-\Delta$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$. In my studies I stumbled upon operators of the form
$$1_{\Gamma_n} (-\Delta -z)^{-1} 1_{\Gamma_m},$$
where $1_{\Gamma_m}$ denotes multiplication with the characteristic function of the cube $\Gamma_m := m + [0,1]^d, m\in \mathbb Z^d$ and $z\in \rho(-\Delta) = \mathbb C \setminus [0,\infty)$. My aim is to prove an estimate for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm:
$$\left \lVert 1_{\Gamma_n} (-\Delta -z)^{-1} 1_{\Gamma_m} \right \rVert_2 \leq C\lvert z \rvert^{-\alpha},$$
$\alpha>0$ being a suitable constant and dimension $d\leq 3$ (otherwise the singularity is too large). In the literature I only found results where the right hand side blows up as $z$ approaches the spectrum, however this is not an issue with the inequality above, where one may send $z$ to some positive real number. I was able to show it in odd dimensions $d=1,3$ due to the possibility of expressing the integral kernel of $(-\Delta -z)^{-1}$ explicitly via spherical Bessel functions; for example in $d=3$
$$(-\Delta -z)^{-1}(x,y) = \frac{1}{4\pi \lvert x - y \rvert}e^{-\sqrt{-z}\lvert x -y \rvert }.$$
From this explicit representations one can deduce an inequality like above. However, I was not able to do this in the even dimension $d=2$ as I lack some nice explicit representation of the involved Bessel function. I would also like to possibly generalize this to larger dimensions $d>3$ by then taking a suitable Schatten $p$-norm, $p=p(d)>2$, so maybe there is some general result that saves me from doing these messy calculations... all help appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, something is not clear to me. If $z$ tends to some positive real number, the norm should blow up, but your estimates implies it stays bounded. Do you want such an estimate in a sector?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I want something like $\sup_{\operatorname{Re }z = a, -1\leq \operatorname{Im }z \leq 1} \lVert 1_{\Gamma_n} (- \Delta -z)^{-1} 1_{\Gamma_m} \rVert_2 < \infty$, where $a>0$. I think this should be valid by just looking at the $L^2$ norm of the kernel in e.g. $d=3$.

Comment: If $d=3$ you use only $|(-\Delta-z)^{-1}(x,y)| \leq C|x-y|^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, but how about $d=2$ or $d>3$ if $d$ even and one looks at e.g. $\lVert \cdot \rVert_4$?

Comment: Let me use the notation $(\lambda-\Delta)^{-1}$ for consistency. Then $(\lambda-\Delta)^{-1}f=v_\lambda*f$, $\lambda \not \in ]-\infty,0]$,  and $v_\lambda (r)=\lambda^{(d-2)/2} v_1(r\sqrt \lambda)$. $v_1$ satisfies the Bessel kind equation $v''+(n-1)/r \ v'=v$ and has the behavior $v_1(r) \approx r^{2-d}$ as $r \to 0$ (or $\log r$ when $d=2$) and $v_1(r) \approx r^{(1-d)/2}e^{-r}$ as $r \to \infty$. These facts should be the analogues of what you used for $d=3$. I did not check all the details, please let me know if things are unclear (or maybe some point is wrong).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I think this is correct. But the behavior in $d=2$ as $r\to0$ is not enough for my purposes since it causes $v_\lambda(r)$ to blow up, while I need it to stay bounded when $\sqrt{\lambda}$ approaches some positive real number.

Comment: Thanks and let me know. Do you think that your conjecture fails for $d=2$?

Comment: I don't think it fails. I read in a book of Barry Simon that in $d=2$, while it is true that the kernel does not have a limit as $\sqrt{\lambda} \to 0$, it does have one when it approaches a limit $\alpha > 0$. However, he did not gave a proof of this fact. Since I did not find any explicit representation nor an asymptotic expansion for this case, I wasn't able to prove it so far...